# Try to draw Mexican hat function. But got error "?? Error using ==> mtimes Inner matrix dimensions must agree."

Tags: matlab

I try to draw the Mexican hat function using Matlab.

[image]

```
x=-20:20;
y=-20:20;
z=(1 - x.^2 -y.^2) * exp(-1/2 * (x.^2 + y.^2))
```

But I got error:

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

How should do to I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two bugs here. First, you want to create your `x` and `y` using something like `meshgrid`, so that they are arrays rather than vectors (and while we're at it, let's look at a more edifying range for the function...)

```
>> [x y] = meshgrid(-5:0.5:5, -5:0.5:5);
```

Second, you want element-wise multiplication instead of matrix multiplication (`.*` instead of `*`).

```
>> z = (1 - x.^2 -y.^2) .* exp(-1/2 * (x.^2 + y.^2));
```

That should do the trick:

```
>> surf(z)
```

[image]